# Looking to fix main.cpp no match for `std::istream& << int&' operator

Tags: c++

To start, here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int add(int x,int y){
    return x+y;
}

int sub(int x,int y){
    return x-y;
}

int divide(int x,int y){
    return x/y;
}

int mult(int x,int y){
    return x*y;
}

void operation(string operation,int x,int y){
    if(operation=="addition"){
        cout << add(x,y);
    }
    else if(operation=="subtraction"){
        cout << sub(x,y);
    }
    else if(operation=="multiplication"){
        cout << mult(x,y);
    }
    else if(operation=="division"){
        cout << divide(x,y);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  while(true){
    string operation;
    int x;
    int y;
    cout << "Please enter your operation: ";
    cin >> operation;
    cout << endl << "Please enter the first number: ";
    cin << x;
    cout << endl << "Please enter the second number: ";
    cin << y;
    cout << endl;
    operation(operation,x,y)
    }
  }
  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that I want to have x and y be inputted by the user using cin, but for some reason I get the error shown in the title ( main.cpp no match for `std::istream& << int&' operator ) I think it may have something to do with the way I initialized the variable but I don't know if it could be something else.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Should be `cin >> x;` and `cin >> y;`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ***[A Gentle Introduction to C++ IO Streams](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++-iostreams.html)***. You should use << for cout and >> for cin.